# network topology graph/image on router cli

Tags: networking, graphics, command-line, router

Please redirect to correct forum if needed.

Problem: when I am on a router, I want to know, where my router is in the topology. Where all its connected to. I can check by looking at my configuration but that less friendly. I want to do that same task by askii image. (askii - because on router, you cant render anything else - afaik).

Please guide me if there is something like this available already that I can use. I can feed the information it needs (the connection type/speed/point) and it should be able to graph/image it out. I want to see that on Command line interface (cli) only.

Comment: Should this be posted somewhere else? any one?

Comment: I think Server Fault would be a better site for this. I'll go ahead and flag it. It's not really clear to me which site networking related questions should go to, but Server Fault seems like the best match. (Networking questions that are in some way programming related belong here.)

Answer (score 0):

I know there are various commercial tools to do this, but you might want to check [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), which is a free one. (I am not sure any of them out output a text-based map, but at that point you wouldn't be relying on the router to render it for you, so why would it need to be text-based?)

I don't think most (any?) routers support this sort of thing. The closest you'll get is `show` commands which display the peering information for your routing protocols in table format.